# test for a specific element placement relative to other elements python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, logic, element

Ok, I have a lists of lists, which are integers. Some of the child lists are simply `[0]`, which is a good thing. I like these `[0]`'s and I need at least one `[0]` between each element `!= [0]`. I have been struggling with these `for` loops, `if` statements, and python's `any()` function to create the mess you see below, and while it gives no errors, it simply does not work. It changes nothing. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to solve this?

```
for r in range(0,len(combinations)):
        if any( (combinations[r][e] != [0]) and (combinations[r][e-1] != [0]) and (combinations[r][e+1] != [0]) for e in range(1,len(combinations[r])-1)):
            del combination[r]
```

Below I added an example of what a typical `combinations` list would look like.

```
[([1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0]),
 ([1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1]),
 ([1, 1], [1, 1], [0], [0]),
 ([1, 1], [1, 1], [0], [0]),
 ([1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1]),
 ([1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0])]
```

Below this is the kind of data the I would like to end up with.

```
[([1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0]),
 ([1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1]),
 ([1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1]),
 ([1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0])]
```

You can see that the two lists in the parent list with `!= [0]` elements adjacent to each other have removed because there was not a `[0]` between them. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
combinations = [([1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0]),
            ([1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1]),
            ([1, 1], [1, 1], [0], [0]),
            ([1, 1], [1, 1], [0], [0]),
            ([1, 1], [0], [0], [1, 1]),
            ([1, 1], [0], [1, 1], [0])]

def filterComb(comb):
    result = list()
    for current in comb:
        isok = True
        for i in range(1, len(current)):
            if current[i] != [0] and current[i-1] != [0]:
                isok = False
                break
        if isok:
            result.append(current)
    return result

combinations = filterComb(combinations)
```

Comment: Wow! That is incredible! What on earth is that `<>` operator?

Comment: It's just an equivalent of !=

Comment: I'd say always use `!=`. Since `<>` isn't clear and it has been removed since Python 3.x.